# Install self-signed certificate to personal store from .cer file using c++

Tags: certificate, cryptoapi

I try to create a certificate for testing purposes in two steps. First, I create a self-signed certificate which establishes my own Certification Authority (CA). Second, I use that root certificate to sign a test server certificate which will be placed in personal certificate store. I open an administrative command prompt and enter the following:

**Step 1:**
MakeCert -pe -n "CN=TestCA" -b 01/01/2015 -e 01/01/2020 -ss my -sr currentuser -a sha256 -sky signature -len 2048 -r "TestCA.cer"

**Step 2:**
MakeCert -pe -n "CN=localhost" -b 01/01/2015 -e 01/01/2020 -eku 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1 -in "TestCA" -is my -ir currentuser -ss my -sr currentuser -a sha256 -sky exchange -sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12 -len 2048 "Localhost.cer"

Following those steps, everything works fine. After that, I try to install those certificates via c++ application. It seems to be fine when I check those certificates in certmgr.msc, however, client always fail to connect to server since then. After deleting certificate "localhost" from personal certificate store, then do step 2 using MakeCert.exe again. Client can success to connect to server. Maybe there is something important that I was missing. If anyone knows it, please give me some suggestions. By the way, my client and server are running in the same computer. My codes are shown below.

```
HCERTSTORE hMyCertStore = NULL;
if(hMyCertStore = CertOpenStore(
   CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,          // The store provider type
   0,                               // The encoding type is
                                    // not needed
   NULL,                            // Use the default HCRYPTPROV
   CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER,  // Set the store location in a
                                    // registry location
   L"MY"                            // The store name as a Unicode 
                                    // string
   ))
{
    printf("The system store was created successfully.\n");
}
else
{
    printf("An error occurred during creation "
        "of the system store!\n");
    exit(1);
}

CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO importSrc;

memset(&importSrc, 0, sizeof(CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO));
importSrc.dwSize = sizeof(CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO);
importSrc.dwSubjectChoice = CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SUBJECT_FILE;
importSrc.pwszFileName = L"C:\\Temp\\MakeCert\\localhost.cer";
importSrc.pwszPassword = L"";
importSrc.dwFlags = CRYPT_EXPORTABLE | CRYPT_USER_PROTECTED;

if (CryptUIWizImport(CRYPTUI_WIZ_NO_UI,
                     NULL,
                     NULL,
                     &importSrc,
                     hMyCertStore) == 0)
{
    printf("CryptUIWizImport error %d\n", GetLastError());
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Clement

Answer (score 0):

I've found the difference between MakeCert and my application. After installing by MakeCert, I opened certificate dialog's General tab, then I found there is a string "You have a private key that corresponds to this certificate, but using my application, there is no string in the dialog. I think that I've missed some steps during the install procedure. If anyone know, please give me some suggestion.

Thanks.

Clement